# problems with shell_exec, does not work properly with some bash commands

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu, echo

I have the following script

```
$variable1="echo -e \'Hi\n how are you\'";
$variable2=shell_exec("$variable1");
echo "$variable2";
```

And theorically should show 'Hi' and in another line 'how are you', but instead it shows this: -e 'Hi
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's bash that's being used? What does `echo shell_exec('echo $SHELL');` give you?

Comment: Why `-e`? _-e enable interpretation of the following backslash escapes_

Comment: This is correct. `shell_exec` does not work with bash commands. It only works with sh commands.